# PROLOG: longest path in graph

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I have this algorithm for shortest path in a graph but now I need to adapt it to get the longest path, i mean, the path with higher value of the edges

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y],L):- 
    edge(X,Y,L).

path(X,Y,[X|W],L):- 
    edge(X,Z,L1), 
    path(Z,Y,W,L2), 
    L is L1 + L2.


shortestPath(X,X,[X,X],0):- !.
shortestPath(X,Y,MinP,MinD):-
    findall([L,P],path(X,Y,P,L),Set),
    sort(Set,Sorted),
    Sorted = [[MinD,MinP]|_].
```

any help?

thank you

Comment: edge(...) relates to the knowledge base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sort/2` puts them in shortest-first order, then the longest should be the last entry in `Sorted`.

See [`last/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=last/2), [`append/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3), and (more expensively) [`reverse/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=reverse/2).